# Pass url query parameter to Accounts.onCreateUser

Tags: meteor, facebook-login, server-side, meteor-accounts, twitter-login

I have simple request, I have login route with some URL query like this:

```
www.example.com/login?id=xxxyyyzzz
```

Depending of id I need to add field inside user document. So I need this id inside my Accounts.onCreateUser.

Well this is easy for email/password registration

```
Accounts.createUser({email: 'john.doe@example.com', password: 'xxx', 'extra_param': 'xxxyyyzzz'}, function(err, res){});
```

But this turns out to be imposible for "loginWithService". And I realy need login with Facebook and Twitter.

Is there any other way to grab this id on server side? I use IronRouter, if this can help.

Any hint or suggestion?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm also working on a referral component and have the same issue with social logins (google, facebook)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to have a look at [the official MeteorJS documentation about Accounts.createUser](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser)

Additionally to the 'email' and 'password' fields, you can add a 'profile' object.
You can put any object or property inside it.

If you need to get the query parameter with [Iron Router](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/) inside your template, you can use:

```
     Router.current().params.query.your_query_key

     // in your case
     Router.current().params.query.id
```

Edit:
On the server side, you can also have routes, below is an example in the Iron Router guide:

```
 Router.route('/item', function () {
  var req = this.request;
  var res = this.response;
  res.end('hello from the server\n');
  }, {where: 'server'});
```

However I don't think that you can use Router.current() on the server side.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Hi, sorry I guess I didn't describe my problem very well.

I know that I can add extra parameters when you register user with username and password, which I mention. My problem here is that I cannot add additional parameter when user try to login with facebook for the first time. This method will call Accounts.onCreateUser on server side, so I wonder is there a way to pass down additional param. Official Meteor documentation doesn't say nothing about it.

Maybe it is impossible, or maybe I need some simple override of loginWithFacebok and loginWithTwitter code.

Comment: You are right with Router.current().params.query.id I can grab my id from client side. But I cannot do that on server side. As a matter of fact Iron Router doesn't have any similar global variable on server side. Or maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: Hi Sorry for the late reply, I've edited my original answer:
You can have a router only on the server side, but I don' t think that you can use Router.current().
As a workaround, you can maybe use a method on the client side and use your path_id  as a parameter  to execute Accounts.createUser on the server side ?